# How to mask dynamically specific columns from multiple tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  multiple tables like  EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYEEMail and more tables.
For reference purpose I'm putting some sample data and 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  dept TEXT NOT NULL,
  phone bigint
);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0001, 'Clark', 'Sales',9001234567);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0002, 'Dave', 'Accounting',9000123456);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0003, 'Ava', 'Sales',9000012345);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEEMail (
  empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  MailID TEXT NOT NULL,
  AlternateMail TEXT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEMail VALUES (0001, 'hello123@gmail.com','hi123@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEMail VALUES (0002, 'good123@gmail.com','bye123@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEMail VALUES (0003, 'super123@gmail.com','fast123@gmail.com');
```

**Query** :

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(phone, 1, 6), REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(phone) - 6)) AS masked_phone
FROM `EMPLOYEE`;

select  
CONCAT(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`MailID`, '@', -1)) as phone,
CONCAT(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`AlternateMail`, '@', -1)) as AlternateMail
from EMPLOYEEMail;
```

Output:

**masked_phone**

```
900123****
900012****
900001****
```

**phone                         AlternateMail**

```
d8883d67@gmail.com  d8883d92@gmail.com
d8883dd0@gmail.com  d8883dde@gmail.com
d8883df3@gmail.com  d8883dff@gmail.com
```

It is working fine up to select query But I need to mask multiple columns  all will come in Comma separated values like this

```
(MailID ,AlternateMail,Phone,SSN,BankAccount,Addrress)
```

I'm looking for a loop statement where I will compare these values with
Information_schema.columns table which ever the column matches the with given values .

I'm trying to loop those into Dynamic select statement with @column and @tablename and load the masked values into temp table.
Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Your first query could be written easier `SELECT INSERT(phone,7,10,"****") as  masked_phone FROM EMPLOYEE;` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67697265d792d0af4e7f11f057cb25cf

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes agree we can write in multiple ways. But I'm looking for dynamic loop

Comment: You need in dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

Comment: yes looking for that @Akina

Comment: Often it is required to join or group by obfuscated values for example calculate distinct emails. I'd suggest to use deterministic one-way function like sha256 instead non-deterministic obfuscation. sha256 does not allow to recover original value but allows to join and groupby to work the same as with non-obfuscated values

Comment: @leftjoin thanks for the suggestion but I'm looking  for an answer to achieve the above question

Comment: *But I need to mask multiple columns all will come in Comma separated values like this* Not "like" - show precise desired output for shown sample data.

Comment: Also - what if specified column name is present in more than one table?

Answer (score 0):

I think **substring** is prettier than **masking** email addresses and this way sensitive data will remain secret.

```
SELECT CONCAT("****", SUBSTRING(`EMPLOYEEMail`.`MailID`, LOCATE('@', `EMPLOYEEMail`.`MailID`) - 4 )) AS MailID, 
CONCAT("****", SUBSTRING(`EMPLOYEEMail`.`AlternateMail`, LOCATE('@', `EMPLOYEEMail`.`AlternateMail`) - 4 )) AS AlternateMail, 
INSERT(`EMPLOYEE`.`phone`,7,10,"****") as masked_phone
FROM EMPLOYEE
JOIN EMPLOYEEMail ON EMPLOYEE.empId=EMPLOYEEMail.empId;
```

With your solution (fully masked the username from the email addresses) the query becomes meaningless because nothing refers to the original data

Comment: I have multiple tables  I want to handle  same columns an all the tables

Comment: You can extend this query with multiple joins and add more fields to the select.

Comment: they are key columns are different from each other then How can I join those even column names are matching

Comment: then you need to introduce **alias** names for the same named columns. e.g.: SELECT table1.name AS t1_name, table2.name AS t2_name, .... etc...

Comment: can you please go through the question again Sir . I want a  dynamic query using Information_scheam tables

Comment: I think you can not compare values from your tables with **information_schema.columns** table because this table only contains the configuration of the tables and field but not the duplication of your tables

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the concept of **[View](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)** to achieve this?. One of the benefits of ***Views*** is to hide specific information from the original table or visualize it in another way, without touching the original data.

In your case, you just need to create a view with the query above to hide the specific part of the phone number, email...etc.

```
CREATE VIEW employee_info_encrypted AS
    SELECT  CONCAT(SUBSTR(phone, 1, 6), REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(phone) - 6)) AS masked_phone,
            CONCAT(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`MailID`, '@', -1)) as phone,
            CONCAT(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`AlternateMail`, '@', -1)) as AlternateMail
    FROM `EMPLOYEE`
    inner join EMPLOYEEMail on EMPLOYEEMail.empId = EMPLOYEE.empId;
```

Then, by running the below query you will get the masked info:

```
select * from employee_info_encrypted;
```

Whenever you want to add a new column for example to the response, you just change the **View** code, and it will change the response based on the new conditions.

Comment: if they are multiple tables  then how Need to achieve this. I'm looking for dynamic one

Comment: In all the ways, you need to configure that these specific columns need to be masked. So, from my view, why don't you configure these columns by writing a view for the whole table, and then you can copy the same for the other tables?. To simplify it more, you can create masking functions in your DB, so all you have to do later is basically: "maskPhone(phone)", or "maskEmail(MailID)".